# How to compute the time of upward movement of a Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Suppose $B(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion. Does it make sense to compute the total time of upward movement
$$\int_0^t I(dB_\tau>0)d\tau$$
where $I$ is the characteristic function? What is a rigorous way to define it if it does make sense? Intuition dictates that the expectation of the above integral should be $\frac t2$. I am aware of [Doob's upcrossing lemma](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/06/upcrossings-downcrossings-and-martingale-convergence/). Perhaps we can use [local time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_(mathematics)) and [Tanaka's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula). But I do not have a way to define my integral in similar terms.

Comment: If there were such a definition, it's hard to believe it wouldn't just equal $t/2$, which would make it not very useful.

Comment: Since Brownian motion is random, shouldn't the value of this integral technically be a random variable, also? I think you can say that this random variable is equal to $t/2$ almost surely, i.e. with probability 1 the Brownian motion spends equal amounts of time increasing as decreasing.

Comment: There are some negative results that show what *wouldn't* make sense.  E.g. Brownian motion a.s. has no local points of increase, see Theorem 5.14 of [Mörters and Peres](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/205B/bmbook.pdf).

Comment: @RiversMcForge: You are right. I have edited my question.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for bringing my attention to this very interesting theorem. John Dawkins' answer is along the same line. However, this deals with a finite interval around a time point whereas I am more concerned with the "infinitesimal" interval. I am thinking more in the spirit of the local time. The probability measure of the Brownian motion staying at any particular value in any finite time interval is also $0$. Do you have more suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

One answer to your question, in the negative, is this: With probability 1 the Brownian motion has no times of increase; that is, the probability that there exists a time $t>0$ and a $\delta>0$ such that $\sup_{s\in[t-\delta,t]}B_s=\inf_{s\in[t,t+\delta]}B_s$ is $0$.
This result if due to Dvoretzky, Erdos, & Kakutani ["Nonincrease everywhere of the Brownian motion process", (1961)]. A wonderful and quite brief proof was found thirty years later by K. Burdzy ["On nonincrease of Brownian motion" (1990)].

Comment: (+1) for the reference to Burdzy's paper.

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention to this very interesting theorem along with the wonderful proofs. Nate Eldredge's comment is along the same line. However, this deals with a finite interval around a time point whereas I am more concerned with the "infinitesimal" interval. I am thinking more in the spirit of the local time. The probability measure of the Brownian motion staying at any particular value in any finite time interval is also $0$. Do you have more suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

for almost any $\omega$, $ \tau \mapsto I_{B_\tau > 0}$ is a measurable function (since $B$ is continuous). You can therefore define and calculate $$\int_0^tI_{B_\tau>0}d\tau$$ for almost any $\omega$.

However, it is not constantly equal to $\frac t2$: why would it be?

What we can say is that its expected value is $\frac t2$, indeed $$ \mathbb E\Bigg[\int_0^tI_{B_\tau>0}d\tau\Bigg] = \int_0^t\mathbb E\Big[I_{B_\tau>0}\Big]d\tau = \int_0^t\frac12d\tau = \frac t2.$$

Comment: This does not answer my question. You have miscomprehended my question and mistranslated it into something different. $B_\tau>0$ is **not** what I am after. I want the infinitesimal upward step $dB_\tau>0$ not the positive $B_\tau$.

Comment: I apologise, I misread the question!